# Неправильно выводит html

Tags: php, tinymce, print, echo

Всем привет, есть маленькая проблема - вывожу текст с бд MySql методом echo или print - результат: весь текст одинаковый, хотя видно в html что он должен быть другой. Заполняю бд с помощью pdo->quote.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Всем огромное спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Эм, нам совершенно ничего не видно.

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы ожидаете и что в действительности выводится. Из вашего скрина ничего не понятно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Маргины у вас отработали - это видно на вашем скрине. Из остального: 
padding у вас везде 0 - тоже похоже на правду
font-size у вас 14px, судя по скрину - это тоже похоже на правду
font-family вроде тоже в порядке.

Предлагаю вам для тестирования сделать следующее: добавьте font-weight и/или добавьте color некоторым тегам в вашем тексте перед сохранением в бд и после вывода вы сразу заметите все ли в порядке со стилями.